# Java Code Doesn't Execute in Order

Tags: java, netbeans, awt

I have the following code in which what I actually want is that when I click the button, the jLabel should show '1' and then click an image of it and save and then for '2', '3' and so on...

```
private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            Numbers.setText(""+i);
            System.out.println("Begin"+i);
            BufferedImage image = null;
            try {
                image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            } catch (AWTException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Flash_Cards.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("E:/Data/Card_" + i + ".png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Flash_Cards.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("End"+i);
        }
    }
```

But I am getting these images instead:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update:**  My file structure:

[image]

Comment: What do you think is executing out of order?

Comment: your question is not clear. tell me exactly what u r doing?

Comment: See the thing is that i believe that the label should get renamed first

Comment: It looks like he's expecting to see a label get updated in his app window with each loop iteration. I have a feeling that it's because this method is running on the event dispatch thread but I don't know enough about Swing to say for sure.

Comment: @MikeB Yah exactly, I want to create some images so i want the label to get changed in each image

Comment: Where, exactly, is your code updating a label?

Comment: @HotLicks `Numbers.setText(""+i);`

Comment: loop seems worthless to me, as u r setting the text of the same label everytime

Comment: Could you add your code that constructs the UI.  Where and how are you adding the `Numbers` label to the UI?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 3) We didn't need to see 5 screenshots of your IDE.  ..Really.

Comment: I have experience many times android java code not executing in order. For example Activity.requestWindowFeature() causes a crash. So I expected that if I called it, then called Thread.sleep(10 seconds); My app would crash before it had time to sleep. However the app sleeps first, and crashes after. LOL

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I don't think that my solution works either.

If you are updating the label using

```
 Numbers.setText(""+i);
```

then you need to call `revalidate/repaint` on the panel that contains the label

```
 panel.revalidate();
 panel.repaint();
```

Comment: Where and how? :P Sorry i am a newbie

Comment: Right after your call to `Numbers.setText(""+i);`.  I assume you have a panel that contains the `Numbers` label.

Comment: My label is just inside my jFrame, see my update for an image

Comment: Then try `getContentPane().revalidate; getContentPane().repaint();`.

Comment: Right after your call to `Numbers.setText(""+i);`.

Comment: In pastebin code it says `getContentPane().revalidate;` is invalid and yah i am going off to sleep so be back tommorow

Answer (score 0):

I don't do awt/swing so I might be wrong but the actual layout & drawing of `Numbers.setText(""+i);` happens after you've exited the `StartActionPerformed` method. And so you have to capture the image after that has happened. And to do that multiple times you have to do setText, screenCapture, setText, .. in multiple steps. `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` can to my knowledge achieve that by enqueuing actions to happen in sequence. Below code might work

```
private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        final int number = i;
        // enqueue setting a new number
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Numbers.setText("" + number);
            }
        });
        // enqueue taking a screenshot thereof
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BufferedImage image = null;
                try {
                    image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                            .getScreenSize()));
                } catch (AWTException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Flash_Cards.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("E:/Data/Card_" + number + ".png"));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Flash_Cards.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                System.out.println("End" + number);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Still in the images there is no text in the label :P

Comment: @DakshShah well, I guess my assumptions about swing are wrong then :D (try moving the 2nd `SwingUtili...` into the `run` of the first one, might change something) like http://pastebin.com/4ZXvtYBQ

Comment: Using two separate `invokeLater` calls does not gain your anything.  You might as well combines them, which would still keep the order.  But that is probably still not enough.  You would have to `repaint` the UI as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @zapl If I use that pastebin code then there is a different output that all the images come with the label = 4, but i want 1, 2, 3.. in each one respectively

Comment: @Kavka I have absolutely no idea how swing drawing works, I'm essentially just assuming it works similarly enough to Android that a solution like that should work :)  I'm trying to get the EDT to execute setText(1) / repaint / capture / setText(2) / repaint / capture but order is wrong because all `setText`s are already enqueued and so repaint of the first is scheduled after the last setText() which would explain the "4" in the screenshots.

Comment: @DakshShah Ok last try http://pastebin.com/8KZFNSW2 - You better try  Kavka's solution, code starts to look terrible.